# Issue with multiple Switches, NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am running into an issue that is causing a null pointer exception.

The issue is because of the way I have my OnCheckedChanged() method structured. Currently, a different Dialog view is inflated based on  a string that is passed on creation. Based on this view, there are different Switches that are presented to the user.

I am looking for a way to reconfigure the following code so that it does run through all the "if statements" and crash. I would like it to do something similar to a switch(v.getId()) + switch structure.

I am trying to avoid implementing seperate OnCheckedChange listeners for my app.

**Anyone know how I could restructure this to avoid the NullPointerException?**

```
    @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (alertDelete.isChecked()) {
        // The toggle is enabled
        permSet.add("alert_delete");
        Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "CHECKED");
    } else {
        // The toggle is disabled
        permSet.remove("alert_delete");
        Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "UNCHECKED");
    }
    if (autoCreate.isChecked()) {
        // The toggle is enabled
        permSet.add("auto_create");
        Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "CHECKED");
    } else {
        // The toggle is disabled
        permSet.remove("auto_create");
        Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "UNCHECKED");
    }
    if (autoDelete.isChecked()) {
        // The toggle is enabled
        permSet.add("auto_delete");
        Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "CHECKED");
    } else {
        // The toggle is disabled
        permSet.remove("auto_delete");
        Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "UNCHECKED");
    }
    if (autoEdit.isChecked()) {
        // The toggle is enabled
        permSet.add("auto_edit");
        Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "CHECKED");
    } else {
        // The toggle is disabled
        permSet.remove("auto_edit");
        Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "UNCHECKED");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also have a simple method to avoid replications

```
private void checkAndSet(Checkable checkable, String param) {

if (checkable.isChecked()) {
            // The toggle is enabled
            permSet.add(param);
            Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "CHECKED");
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
            permSet.remove(param);
            Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "UNCHECKED");
        }

}
```

and in each case you can call:

```
checkAndSet(autoDelete, "auto_delete");
```

Comment: that checkAndSet would be called from within the onCheckChanged() correct?

Answer (score 0):

Implemented  switch() and the answer above.

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (buttonView.getId()) {
    case R.id.switchAlertDelete:
        if (alertDelete.isChecked()) {
            // The toggle is enabled
            permSet.add("alert_delete");
            Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "CHECKED");
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
            permSet.remove("alert_delete");
            Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "UNCHECKED");
        }
        break;

    case R.id.switchAutomationCreate:

        if (autoCreate.isChecked()) {
            // The toggle is enabled
            permSet.add("auto_create");
            Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "CHECKED");
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
            permSet.remove("auto_create");
            Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "UNCHECKED");
        }

        break;

    case R.id.switchAutomationDelete:

        if (autoDelete.isChecked()) {
            // The toggle is enabled
            permSet.add("auto_delete");
            Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "CHECKED");
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
            permSet.remove("auto_delete");
            Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "UNCHECKED");
        }

        break;

    case R.id.switchAutomationEdit:

        if (autoEdit.isChecked()) {
            // The toggle is enabled
            permSet.add("auto_edit");
            Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "CHECKED");
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
            permSet.remove("auto_edit");
            Log.e("ALERTDELETE", "UNCHECKED");
        }

        break;

    }
```